# call a function for each value in a generic c# collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, generics

I have a collection of integer values in a List collection.
I want to call a function for each value in the collection where one of the function's argument is a collection value. 
Without doing this in a foreach loop... is there a way to accomplish this with a lambda/linq expression?

something like... `myList.Where(p => myFunc(p.Value));` ?

thanks in advance,
-s

Comment: Do you need the values produced by the function or just the side effects of having run the function?

Comment: Is there some reason why you reject the foreach loop solution? I say that a statement should have side effects. If you want to call a side-effecting function on each member of a sequence then a statement specifically designed to do exactly that -- the foreach statement -- seems like the natural choice. Can you explain why you're rejecting the language feature precisely designed to do what you want?

Comment: @Eric Exactly, and I was about to post that. I've never understood why anyone would use `List<T>.ForEach` over **foreach**. Good use of Linq can obfuscate a lot of complicated, nested code; but, sometimes it just seems like people like the way lambda expressions look.

Answer (score 104):

LINQ doesn't help here, but you can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

> *List<T>.ForEach Method*
>
> Performs the specified action on each element of the List.

Example:

```
myList.ForEach(p => myFunc(p));
```

The value passed to the lambda expression is the list item, so in this example `p` is a `long` if `myList` is a `List<long>`.

Comment: thanks- this is exactly what i was looking for and probably saw somewhere but couldn't remember...

Comment: Alternatively, you can just specify `myList.ForEach(myFunc)` if myFunc matches the signature of the expected ForEach delegate.

Comment: Unfortunately, if `myFunc` can only have a `void` return type.

Answer (score 27):

As other posters have noted, you can use `List<T>.ForEach`.

However, you can easily write an extension method that allows you to use ForEach on any `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

Which means you can now do:

```
myList.Where( ... ).ForEach( ... );
```

Answer (score 22):

Yap! You can use `List.ForEach` but the problem is that works only for list (For sure you can change everything to a List on the fly, but **less code more fun :)** ). Beside, you have to use `Action<>` prediction that does not provide any return type.

Anyway there is an answer for what you wanted, you can make it possible in the same way you guessed with `Func<>` but with a tiny trick as below:

I will do everything here on the fly:

```
string[] items = (new string[] { "d", "f" }).
    Select(x => new Func<string>(() => { 
        //Do something here...
        Console.WriteLine(x); 
        return x.ToUpper(); 
    }
)).Select(t => t.Invoke()).ToArray<string>();
```

There are some points here:

**First**, I have defined a string array on the fly that can be replaced by any collection that supports LINQ.

**Second**, Inside of the `Select` one `Func<string>` is going to be declared for each element of the given array as it called **`x`**.

(*Look at the empty parenthesis and remember that when you define a `Func<type**1**, type**2**, ..., type**n**>` always the last type is the return type, so when you write just `Func<string>` it indicates a function that has no input parameter and its return type is string*)

It is clear that we want to use the function over the given array `(new string[] { "d", "f" })`, and that's why I define a function with no parameter and also I have used same variable `x` inside of `Func<>` to refer to the same array elements.

**Third**, If you don't put the *second Select* then you have a collection of two functions that return string, and already they've got their inputs from the first array. You can do this and keep the result in an `anonymous` variable and then call their `.Invoke` methods. I write it here:

```
var functions = (new string[] { "d", "f" }).
       Select(x => new Func<string>(() => { 
          //Do something here...
          Console.WriteLine(x); 
          return x.ToUpper(); 
       }));
string[] items = functions.Select(t => t.Invoke()).ToArray<string>();
```

**Finally**, I've converted the result to an array! Now you have a string array!

Sorry It get long!! I hope it would be useful.

Comment: Since we're already using linq, why not preface the `.ForEach()` with a `.ToList()`? `IEnumerable<T>.ToList<T>` returns an `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the List.ForEach method, as such:

```
myList.ForEach(p => myFunc(p));
```

Answer (score 5):

No - if you want to call a function for each item in a list, you have to call the function for each item in the list.

However, you can use the `IList<T>.ForEach()` method as a bit of syntactic sugar to make the "business end" of the code more readable, like so:

```
items.ForEach(item => DoSomething(item));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ForEach method:

MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wan't to use the ForEach method of `List<T>`, but rather use `IEnumerable<T>` (as one often does when "LINQ:ing"), I suggest [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) written by Jon Skeet, et al.

MoreLINQ will give you ForEach, and also Pipe (and a bunch of other methods), which performs an action on each element, but returns the same `IEnumerable<T>` (compared to void).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mini (yet complete) example.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeCollection : List<Employee>
{ }

private void RunTest()
{
    EmployeeCollection empcoll = new EmployeeCollection();
    empcoll.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeNumber = "1111", HireDate = DateTime.Now });
    empcoll.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeNumber = "3333", HireDate = DateTime.Now });
    empcoll.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeNumber = "2222", HireDate = null });
    empcoll.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeNumber = "4444", HireDate = null });

    //Here's the "money" line!
    empcoll.Where(x => x.HireDate.HasValue == false).ToList().ForEach(item => ReportEmployeeWithMissingHireDate(item.EmployeeNumber));

}
private void ReportEmployeeWithMissingHireDate(string employeeNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("We need to find a HireDate for '{0}'!", employeeNumber);
}
```